# Como puedo hacer mi código de C++ ejecutable en android?

Tags: android, c++

En caso de ser posible, como hago mi codigo de C++ ejecutable en android? El IDE que usé es codeblocks.

Answer (score 3):

El código no es ejecutable en ningun contexto. El código fuente se compila y durante ese proceso se genera código binario que sí puede ser ejecutado.

Ahora bien, como todos sabemos el código binario debe ser específico para cada procesador (o al menos para cada familia). De ahí que el código binario que funciona en un 6086 no va a arrancar en un ARM o un SPARC, por ejemplo.

Además, cada Sistema Operativo tiene un juego de llamadas (la API del SO) diferente, por lo que un código compilado para Windows dificilmente funcionará en Linux o en un MAC.

Dicho esto, para generar código ejecutable para Android necesitas:

- El SDK de Android para poder enlazar con sus librerías.
- Un compilador para cada posible destinatario del software (un compilador por cada arquitectura movil).
- Un IDE en el que te sepas manejar.

Una vez tienes esto te toca configurar el IDE para que sea capaz de realizar compilaciones cruzadas. Es decir, desde tu sistema (Windows/Linux) vas a generar ejecutables pensados para otro SO y otra arquitectura. Los pasos concretos para realizar esta tarea dependen del IDE pero se resumen en "*dar de alta*" los diferentes compiladores en el IDE para que el mismo sea capaz de usarlos para generar código ejecutable.

El último paso consiste en generar una compilación diferente con cada compilador y despachar a cada usuario el binario compatible con su móvil.

La opción B pasa por hacer el programa en Java, que al compilarse en cada móvil te permite librarte de esta problemática en concreto.

Comment: si entiendo la pregunta del OP, quizas lo que busca es usar un codigo que tiene en c++ (supongamos un algoritmo) en android, y para eso puede que lo busca es usar el NDK de android *...Android NDK es un conjunto de herramientas que te permite implementar partes de tu app usando lenguajes de código nativo como C y C++. ...* https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html pero no se si es ha eso a lo que se refiere. Saludos

Comment: Exactamente a eso me refiero, disculpa si me expresé mal, empecé hace pocas semanas a programar